# same named struct(class) with different variables

Tags: .net, class, struct

I have different graphic classes like histogram class, ma class..
they have common variables but different property variables. For example all classes have an id but there are different property variables for every classes. For example, column_width is specific for histogram. Now I want to save all objects( instances of every classes ) using a common class. I mean, I want to write a class with common variables and a struct for properties. It is possible to write it? the properties struct can hold different variables for different classes? I hope I can explain the situation.

Comment: thanks, I remember it but I was not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague, so this is just a sketch answer. You would probably need to be more specific if you need additional answers. Anyway, you can inherit one class from another. Base class is the one that is inherited, derived class is the one that is inheriting. Derived class can access all public and protected members of base class (but not private members). Here's one tiny example (that is not even compiling, but you get the picture):

```
class IdentifiableBase
{
  public string id;
}

class Histogram : IdentifiableBase
{
  protected int column_width;
}

class Ma : IdentifiableBase
{
  protected string some_property_of_ma;
}

class Example
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    IdentifiableBase[] example = new IdentifiableBase[] { new Histogram(), new Ma() };
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", example[0].id, example[1].id);
  }
}
```